# Is it possible to get information about lines going though a certain subway station using a google api?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api, google-places

On a click on a subway station icon from New York (probably from other places, too), a "Subway services" information pop-up shows subway lines going trough that station.

Is this information publicly available? If so, how do you get it?
Unfortunately, google places only returns the following details about a station:

```
{
   "html_attributions" : [],
   "result" : {
   "address_components" : [
     {
        "long_name" : "US",
        "short_name" : "US",
        "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
     }
  ],
  "formatted_address" : "United States",
  "geometry" : {
     "location" : {
        "lat" : 40.6551440,
        "lng" : -74.00354900000001
     }
  },
  "icon" : "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png",
  "id" : "fcaa4ac0ac8dc5bbb153f43bc1efded1448f1ffa",
  "name" : "36 St",
  "reference" : "CnRkAAAAoYZgAvSXmBtIV1tiiu0Bwr8g6A15UoFxfwXxYSFMd2epk4tVw5AxNK-egMHNeaxTDkd-w5s4Hzy0hGpe28KPrAMLh1r5r-0v1VDMe4mith91faxSoqNaceuu1MHMLTlK6v6QKbHYTNXSnxAl0ZEq4RIQgFvP37u4dB6Evb7ZMLXo-hoUXR2sVyfugYJQrMBYqemeCmjbaTQ",
  "types" : [ "subway_station", "train_station", "transit_station", "establishment" ],
  "url" : "https://maps.google.com/maps/place?cid=16447150154827564830",
  "utc_offset" : -240,
  "vicinity" : "United States",
  "website" : "http://www.mta.info/"
   },
    "status" : "OK"
}
```

If you visit the url, though, subway services from this station are displayed.